# Injective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, injective-module, division-ring

Let $R=M_n(D)$ the Matrix ring over a division ring and consider $R$ as a left module over itself. Is $R$ an injective module?

I know that $R$ is free, hence it is projective. 
Is $R$ injective? I were thinking about using Baer's criterion, but don't get it to work. Any hints on that?

Comment: Semisimple rings are *characterized* by the fact *all* their modules are injective.  And projective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is not injective as a left module over itself. Then the injective envelope is a proper essential extension: $R\subset E(R)$.

But $R$ is semisimple, so all $R$ modules, including $E(R)$ are semisimple, so $R$ is a direct summand of $E(R)$. But if $R\oplus C=E(R)$, $R$ isn't an essential submodule unless $C=\{0\}$, a contradiction since $E(R)$ doesn't properly extend $R$ in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The ring $M_n(D)$ is Morita equivalent to $D$. Over a division ring,
every module is free, so is projective. All all modules are projective, then
all modules are injective. Therefore over $M_n(D)$, every module is injective.

Comment: The solution lokks great, but we didn't covered Morita equivalences… Any easy way to avoid that?